# What is the distance between two points on the Berger metric of the squashed three-sphere?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry

The Berger metric on a "squashed" three-sphere is given (in Euler coordinates) by

4 $ds^2 = \lambda^2 (d \tau + \cos \theta d \phi)^2 + d \theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta d \phi^2$.

See for example Eq. 1.11 of [this paper](http://www.fysik.su.se/~ingemar/exjobb/patrik.pdf). This formula describes the geodesic distance between two *infinitesimally* separated points.

My question: what is the geodesic distance between any two points on the Berger sphere?

What is the distance as a function of the coordinates $\tau_1,\phi_1,\theta_1$ and $\tau_2,\phi_2,\theta_2$ of the two points?

Answer (score 2):

Geodesics in Berger sphere become circle arcs in the quotient
$$\tfrac12\cdot\mathbb{S}^2=\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^1=\mathbb{S}^3/\mathbb{S}^1.$$

Once you see it, all calculations should be easy. (But I do not want to calculate.)

Comment: It's easy to write down the explicit formula for the geodesics, but determining the cut locus (except for the 'unsquashed' Berger metric on the $3$-sphere) is highly nontrivial and, even then, 'explicitly' using the exponential mapping to push down the distance function, even locally, requires inverting a mapping that cannot be 'explicitly' inverted. You can compute the power series of the square of the distance from a point to any order you like, of course, with sufficient patience and computing power, but I doubt that there is a 'closed form' expression.

Comment: @RobertBryant I think knowing geodesics is sufficient for all practical needs. In particular a point on a cut locus can be visualized as a lune with explicit condition on curvatures and the area --- it might be as good as a closed form.

Comment: Thank you for these comments. @RobertBryant what you say about cut-loci making it hard to write down an explicit form of the answer sounds plausible, but your argument doesn't seem to rule out being able to get an expression of the form "distance = min_k f(theta_1,phi_1,tau_1,theta_2,phi_2,tau_2,k)" where k runs over some discrete set (e.g. the integers)? The idea would be that k would label the different geodesics connecting the two points, and then you choose the minimum length one?

Comment: @AdamB:  If you want to get a sense of how complicated this 'simple case' can be, have a look at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.05472v3.pdf, where they compute the geodesics, the diameter, the cut locus, etc. of the Berger spheres.  Their notation is different from yours (they don't use Euler coordinates, but use the fact that the Berger spheres are left-invariant metrics on the $3$-sphere that are also right-invariant under a circle action).  Note that they give a recipe for the distance function of the kind you describe but don't compute the distance function 'explicitly' from this description.